# Census 1905 address 89 Madison St. Brooklyn, New York

Tags: census-records, new-york-city, 1900s-decade, address

I would like to see  1905 census for 89 Madison St. Brooklyn, NY.

Comment: Welcome to G&FH, please be sure to review the [tour] and [help] sections on what is a well formed question. Your question as originally asked is a bit general and 'might' be covered by other questions depending on what specifically information you are hoping to achieve from the census record. Use the edit button to help improve your question.

Comment: Where have you looked so far?  The downvote on your question is likely to be due to you not having included any details of your research prior to posting your question.

Comment: @Ilen - Can you explain why you can't search by name, and why you want that particular census. There are a couple of techniques that can be used to find a particular address in a census but those depend on finding neighbours and enumeration district information that narrows the search. If you've already done that, let us know.

Comment: Downvoted for lack of research effort and because the question isn't a question.

Answer (score 1):

This web page (www.stevemorse.org)  offers [searches](http://www.stevemorse.org/nyc/nyc.php?census=1905brooklyn&street=Madison%20St&xstreet=Madison%20St) to locate the relevant ED and AD values(AD = Assembly District, ED = Election District) by street. Those districts are what the census is organized by, and the page then links to appropriate group of pages.

About 20 pages of the 1905 census is covered by those districts, [can be seen here](http://www.stevemorse.org/nyc/viewer.html?census=1905brooklyn&ad=17&ed=12), Madison st. is on pgs 18-20. It doesn't list individual street addresses however.